# .bashrc overwritten but still sourced -- how can it be recovered?

Tags: bash, data-recovery, bashrc

Usually when I find a command I want to alias, I echo it to my .bashrc like so:

```
[up button pressed to last command, then line edited so that it reads]
$echo "command-i-just-did" >> ~/.bashrc
```

There may be a better way to do this. But anyway, just now I overwrote the entire .rc file by using a single chevron. However, since the .bashrc is still current, it's still accepting my old aliases (for now of course). So is there a way to recover it?

Comment: `echo "set -o noclobber" > ~/.bashrc` (remember to add a second angle bracket)

Comment: For next time: [Tips for putting ~ under source control](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1875)

Comment: For the future: Backup your files so this isn't an issue.  You might also consider creating a separate file for these quick add-ons and sourcing it somewhere like in .bashrc. Provides a basic safety net and you can easily turn it on and off as necessary.

Comment: You can save your current settings but if your `.bashrc` had any *logic* in it that depended on local variables like host, user, etc. that is probably unrecoverable.  The real answer is to restore from your most recent backup.  You do have a recent backup right?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- `alias` without parameter outputs the definitions of currently defined aliases.
- `declare -f` outputs the definitions of currently defined functions.
- `export -p` outputs the definitions of currently defined variables.

All those commands output definitions ready to be reused, you can redirect their outputs directly to a new `~/.bashrc`.

All lists will contain a lot of elements defined elsewhere, for example `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bash_completion`. So you will have to clean up the list manually.

Comment: I would also suggest to start from the default `.bashrc` for your system. In Debian it is in `/etc/skel`, or you can create a new user, if you can, to get a brand new `.bashrc`.

Comment: `set` and `declare` (without arguments) display all of this at once.

Comment: @enzotib, great idea. i did wonder where the default .bashrc would reside...

Comment: Be aware that `declare -f >> ~/.bashrc` could perhaps add A LOT of lines to your `.bashrc`. In my case that was **13216** lines because of git, npm and rvm combined.

Answer (score 2):

`typeset -f > .bashrc`
should do it, providing all you had were aliases.

Comment: The `functions` command doesn't exist for me on `4.2.10(2)-release`. You probably mean `declare -f`.

Comment: Actually, I meant "typeset -f"