# How to retrieve lost aliases?

Tags: bash, command-line, alias, bashrc

I made an echo command to my .bash_aliases file and erased all of my aliases, except the test alias.  However, I still have a session open that has the aliases loaded (into the tcl?).  Can I retrieve them from this session?

Comment: What if you just type `alias`? It will show what you have defined.

Comment: Your next question is now required to be about setting up a backup system. :-/

Comment: Your next task, as soon as you've recreated your `.bash_aliases`, is to [set up version control for your dot files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1875/tips-for-putting-under-source-control).

Comment: @Gilles even better: http://unix.blogoverflow.com/2014/04/getting-started-with-version-controlled-configurations/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can almost definitely just do:

```
alias >>./bash_aliases
```

Answer (score 15):

Easy trick

```
for alias in $(compgen -a); do type $alias; done
```

Comment: You, sir or madame, are a life saver.

Comment: Combine this with redirection to a file (`$alias` > `.bash_aliases`, maybe with some file regexes to get it to the right place in the file) and you don't have to type it back into the original file yourself. (That is, if you haven't already typed it in.)

Comment: While this works, I don't see the benefit over just using 'alias'. The format isn't particularly useful by comparison.