# Is there a log of deleted/removed files/directories?

Tags: logs, data-recovery

After a reboot today, for no apparent reason, I seemingly lost a dir `.dotfiles` from inside my `$HOME` dir which held all my config dotfiles.

It will be a huge pain to recreate them but that's what I'm doing now. I have a slightly dated backup to work from.

Is there a log I can view that will show all deleted or removed files and directories, either by me manually, possibly by accident, or by another application maybe?

Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Comment: Just a heads up.  When you're considering doing any form of recovery, you must avoid writing to the same drive.  You probably prevented yourself from restoring anything.  A simple deletion is usually easily reversible when there's nothing that overwrote it.  And to directly answer your question, if you're asking, I'm assuming you haven't set up anything to track these things so no you won't find any logs of it.

Comment: thank you @JuliePelletier . Today I was remote and didn't have a external drive to boot live from so that wasn't an option. I used testdisk for about half an hour and then grepped the results and mostly everything it grabbed was months old rather than hours

Comment: Maybe check your bash history. Directories don't usually just go missing.

Comment: I wonder if it was really lost, or just, as you say, seemingly lost. Did you rename it? Is it a checkout of a Git repository?

Comment: Does this [data recovery](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files) answer your question. It is an another SE question that has a solution using `debugfs`

Answer (score 1):

There is no log of file operations, unless you've explicitly set one up. Setting a log of file operations is unusual and tends to hurt performance.

As [hermancain](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/103531/hermancain) suggested in a comment, you can search your shell history (`less ~/.bash_history` in the default configuration) and try to find a command that removed or moved the directory. This may have been a command with wildcards, so you might not find the actual directory name in the history, only a wildcard pattern that matches it.

In case the directory has been moved, or you misremembered the path, try [`locate somefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locate_(Unix)) where `somefile` is the name of a file that was in this directory, or even part of the name.

Tip: [put your dot files under version control](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1875/tips-for-putting-under-source-control).

Comment: Enabling process accounting would be another option.

Comment: @Kusalananda Process accounting would only tell you something like “this user called `rm` at this time”. It wouldn't tell you which files were removed, or about files removed by an application that isn't obviously about removing files. You'd need something more intrusive such as audit logs.